# How to copy properties from object to another object?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot

When I try to copy all attributes and collections from formation's Object to another formation's object and save it with another id, I get this exception about id. How can I resolve that?

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: identifier of an instance of entity.Formation was altered from 2 to null
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.checkId(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:80)
```

There is my code to copy this formation in `f`:

```java
BeanUtils.copyProperties(f, formation);
return addFormation(f);
```

Comment: Didi you check this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41558854/spring-beanutils-copyproperties-not-working

Comment: Yes of course its not the same situation.

Answer (score 0):

i got same issue when i manipulate the original object before calling BeanUtils.copyProperties, i fixed it by firstly call BeanUtils.copyProperties then manipulate the field of the new object

```
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    Unit unitRecord = (Unit) session.get(Unit.class, 1076L);
    Unit newObject = new Unit();
    
    //////////WORK//////
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(unitRecord, newObject );
    newObject.setId(1077L);
    ////////////
    
    /////////////NOT WORK/////
    unitRecord.setId(1077L);
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(unitRecord, newObject );
    /////////////
    
    newObject.setName("TESTONLY TESTSTST");
    session.save(newObject);
    tx.commit();
```